APT / DPKG Broken After mysql-server-8.0 update on Ubuntu 20.04.5
During monthly patching [security updates only], it updated mysql-server-8.0 from [0/8.0.36/0ubuntu0.20.04.1/X86_64] to mysql-server-8.0[0:8.0.37-0ubuntu0.20.04.3] however as it tries to continue patching I get the following error:
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.37-0ubuntu0.20.04.3) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/mysql-server-8.0.postinst: line 56: kill: (2401867) - Permission denied

However, even though mysql seems to be updated & running okay, this update broke dpkg...
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.

WARNING: Could not install the python3-apt, this may cause the patching operation to fail.

failed to run commands: exit status 1

When I trying to run dpkg --configure -a [after sudo su root], I hit the same permission denied issue... Why did this happen and how do I fix my apt? We are using mysql and cannot afford to lose data, so I'd like to avoid uninstall/purging especially since it looks like mysql is working w/o any issues....
For Reference:
Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-1062-aws


How exactly are you applying the security update? Are you doing it from a terminal emulator - and if so, which one?

I'm using AWS Systems Manager's AWS-RunPatchBaseline document... Under the hood it looks like they are running a python script that does the patching.

OK thanks - the reason I asked is it sounds a lot like this bug report where it turned out that the issue was actually that the update was being run from inside a containerized terminal

AHHHHH!!!! Running it from a direct ssh worked!!! What happened was I was using AWS Session Manager to run the command since that was the only thing I had access to... I saw that post a few days ago and only tried to stop apparmor and retry which didn't work, but just now I got my manager to do a real ssh and it worked! If you could phrase that as an answer I'll accept it as a response!

Why don't you go ahead and post an answer yourself - I'm not familiar with AWS at all

Alright, I'll post the answer. Thought it would be polite to give you the credit. Thank you so much!!!!!

Fixed by using a direct SSH connection instead of AWS Session Manager to run:
sudo su root
dpkg configure -a

Thanks to @steeldriver who mentioned that the update might be running inside a containerized terminal. It turns out that AWS Session Manager, which was the only way I had permission to access the server, is likely doing this because it causes update permission issues.
